# "Emulating" /var/include path in Windows7 in WAMP setup

Tags: php, linux, windows-7, path

I have to run a php application that includes config files from (hardcoded) "/var/include/xxx"  within a Windows7 WAMP setup (i'm using http://www.ampps.com). My Question is: is there a proper way to emulate linux paths here ?

Comment: I would think there should be a config file where you can edit `/var/include/` to a windows path (or another path). Isn't that more practical than hacking windows ?

Comment: Consider using php.ini include_path directive.